# Symfony error : Cannot connect to DB after DB update

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I had my Symfony 2 website connected to a MySQL DB, everything was find, but after changing my contract with my host provider, I needed tu update my datas on a new DB, with new names. I created the new DB, php myAdmin shows me that everything is fine on that side.

I updated the paramaters.yml file as follow in my symfony project:

```
parameters:
database_host: newdbhostname.db.1and1.com
database_port: 3306
database_name: newdbname
database_user: newdbusername
database_password: **********
mailer_transport: mail
mailer_host: null
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: *sameasbefore*
```

But since then, I cannot connect to the DB, and have this weird error:

Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /homepages/37/d627732413/htdocs/billetterielouvre/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 43

This part corresponds to:

```
    public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null, array $options = null)
    {
        try {
LINE 43 --> parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);  
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement', array()));
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            throw new PDOException($exception);
        }
    }
```

I cleared the cache through ssh on the server, but still this error happens. Does anybody have an idea to help me find what needs to be fixes there ?

Thanks!

Comment: System can't convert host `newdbhostname.db.1and1.com` to ip address. Check host name or set ip address of db server instead of host name.

Comment: clear the cache manually. Delete var/cache/prod directory

Comment: Thank you Mintho433, clearing the cache manually did the trick, seems like doing it from composer on this host provider is limited. Max P., it looks like newdbhostname.db.1and1.com is accepted as that, maybe your statement depends of the host provider you're using? Anyway, thanks to all of you for helping me, cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You should clean the cache.

`rm -rf app/cache/*`

Does the new provider allow connecting from external networks?

Try creating a script in plain old PHP and see if you can connect

With SSH on the server, can you resolve the host of the db? Try `nslookup newdbhostname.db.1and1.com` and then `telnet newdbhostname.db.1and1.com 3306`

Comment: Thanks ste, I cleared the cache manually at the end, that did the trick. Composer didn't cleared it fully apparently, through this host provider.